# Make the "all queues" link on the Review Queues dropdown persistent

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

While in the process of completing one's daily review tasks, the Review Queue dropdown looks similar to this:

[image: before completing]

Note the "all queues" link, which handily redirects to the site's `/review` page, allowing one to look at queue numbers and one's own statistics for each queue. This is especially useful for those nearing completion for the [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer) or [Steward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward) badges, as those badges cannot be tracked from the user profile page and it's nice to be able to check up on them easily.

However, once a user has reached their maximum daily review tasks, that handy-dandy button *disappears*:

[image: after completing]

Some may argue that it's smart UX to remove the option when the user doesn't need it anymore, but I say that it's *much* less painful to click twice than it is to click-and-drag-the-URL-then-type-review-then-press-enter.

I think a change to always include the "all queues" button, regardless of daily task completion, would be a helpful one. Thoughts?

Comment: Middle mouse how? If there's no link to the `/review` page, what's there to click on?

Comment: @JJJ Neither my laptop nor any of my mobile devices have a middle mouse button.

Comment: @JJJ Well color me tickled. Works like a charm. However, I'll let my feature request stand, as it's not obvious that that's the solution if all you've ever seen is the dropdown functionality. And I will mention that I don't see the review button *at all* on mobile once I've completed the dailies.

Comment: @JJJ:  Perhaps you should post your suggestion as an answer.  But, in any case, please post it in greater detail.  I tried what I believe you’re saying, and it doesn’t work, so perhaps I don’t understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On request, I'll post my comment as an answer.

Alternatively, what works for me is to use the fact that there's a hyperlink under the review menu button.

To illustrate this, please consider the screenshot of my browser window below. As you can see, my cursor is hovering over the review queue button. When I click with the left button it opens a menu similar to the screenshot in the question. But when we pay attention to the bottom left corner of the browser, we see a link. By pressing the middle mouse button in this position we don't trigger JavaScript like we would with the left mouse button but instead we open the link in a new tab.

This works on Windows if you can normally open links in new tabs using the middle mouse button. I don't know if or how it works on other operating systems, but I'd try whatever combo you use to open in a new tab. I've also tried `CTRL+LMB` but that doesn't work, it still triggers the JavaScript. Turning off JavaScript and then using a normal left mouse button also works, but that may impact other elements of the site, I'm not sure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.   OK; I guess I understood it correctly.   It doesn’t work in Internet Explorer on my Windows 7 system (although middle-click on ordinary textual links does open them in a new tab, and your answer does work for me in Firefox).

Answer (score 2):

I couldn’t get [JJJ’s answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336655/195817#195817) to work in Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7. 
However, (right click) → “Open link” does seem to work.

Comment: Stop using the table support announcement as testing ground. We have [actual sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox?r=SearchResults) for this. Thanks.